# How to write marker messages into the MySQL general_log?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6, logs

I'm build a performance testing harness for our distributed web app. I'm using JMeter to drive it by simulating poorly performing parts of the app from the web side. I've set up MySQL to log to the general_log table. Now I would like to have JMeter send marker messages into the general_log so that, after identifying a poorly performing segment, I can fetch all of the queries run between markers surrounding that segment for further analysis.

I've tried sending an INSERT query on the table, but it always returns `Error : You can't use locks with log tables.` and my row is not created (but the INSERT query itself shows up).  I was hoping to send a customized message, but this doesn't work.

So, how do I insert a test run specific message into the general_log? Alternately, is there another solution? I was thinking of adding a table similar to the general_log table for my use, but we have a variety of deployments and being able to run this test on any of them without modification would be ideal.

Comment: what if you insert something into table having one field of varchar(50) and the values could be " Start of the activity...." and after the batch insert something like "end of activity..." to a customized table..hope it helps

Comment: Please run `SELECT engine FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mysql' and table_name='general_log';` What storage engine is the table ???

Comment: @NawazSohail, yes, that is what I am trying to do, write a marker to the table.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, the table is MyISAM and that is what your query returns. I've already converted the table and indexed it as I have seen you recommend a number of times, thank you for the idea and instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `mysql.general_log` already converted to MyISAM and indexed, I would recommend making snapshots of that table based on a timestamp range. What I mean by snapshot is a temp table that contains just the events you wish to mark.

Suppose you want to log entries from the last 10 minutes. This Dynamic SQL should do it for you :

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0; ## Do this so it does not replicate to slaves
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myloggingdatabase;
USE myloggingdatabase
SET @now = NOW();
SET @ten_minutes_ago = @now - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
SET @snapshot = CONCAT('general_log_',DATE_FORMAT(@now(),'%Y%m%d_%H%M%00'));
SET @sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',@snapshot);
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@snapshot,' LIKE mysql.general_log');
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@snapshot,' SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log');
SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' WHERE event_time>=',QUOTE(@ten_minutes_ago));
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

If you want all the events from yesterday, do this

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0; ## Do this so it does not replicate to slaves
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myloggingdatabase;
USE myloggingdatabase
SET @now = NOW();
SET @midnight_today = DATE(@now) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
SET @midnight_yesterday = @midnight_today - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
SET @snapshot = CONCAT('general_log_',DATE_FORMAT(@midnight_today(),'%Y%m%d_%H%M%00'));
SET @sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',@snapshot);
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@snapshot,' LIKE mysql.general_log');
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',@snapshot,' SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log');
SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' WHERE event_time>=',QUOTE(@midnight_yesterday));
SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' AND event_time<',QUOTE(@midnight_today));
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

You will to have discard those temp tables now and then by simply running

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myloggingdatabase;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: I think that might work well. It occurred to me that I can send `SELECT NOW() FROM DUAL;` which will not only appear in the general_log, but will return the timestamp for that particular entry. I will try having my JMeter pause for a bit then send that between every segment. I'm off to try it out, thanks!

Comment: In MySQL it is simply `SELECT NOW();`.

Comment: Even better, thanks! And It just occurred to me that I can mark my message in the select: `SELECT NOW(), "message with X marker";`

Comment: @FranK. why not write that as an answer ?

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer when I have it working. After decades of working in software I've noticed that having data to back up my claims is the best situation. So I always wait until I have proof that a concept is working before claiming it works in public.

Comment: The system I am building has many moving parts, so it is not sufficient to only apply your scripts to a test database, I have to verify that it will work everywhere. That said, it looks like a good solution so far!